# Reading data from the console

Tags: c++, linux, macos, console

I have written a console application that has its own command prompt when run.  Unfortunately I could not simply call std::cin and wait on input because I need to interpret up/down for the purpose of a command history.

Instead I had to turn off echo and put the console into noncanonical mode, and use the 'read' command to get each character one by one, echo them back if they are printable characters, or attempt to parse/interpret them if its the start of an escape code.

The problem I run in to is that is difficult to read and parse the various escaped codes in a generalized/generic fashion.  It becomes even more problematic when I have to read/parse the responses to the size/position queries.

Is there a better way to read from the terminal?  Is there a special function that can read/parse the special terminal codes?  ncurses is not a viable option (it clears the screen, and even just using filter() seems overkill), and other applications do this all the time, without having to pull in these dependancies...what am I doing wrong?

Here is a snipped of my current 'getch' function which does a very limited (and with more advanced codes, broken) read.

```
int getch_ex()
{
    int buf = 0;
    size_t count = read(0, &buf, 1);
    if ((count > 0) && (buf == ESCAPE_CODE))
    {
        size_t count = read(0, &buf, 1); // [
        if ((count > 0) && (buf == '['))
        {
            count = read(0, &buf, 2);
        }
    }
    return (buf);
}
```

How do other terminal applications with prompts (grub, python, etc...) achieve this?

My primary target is Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library.  It sounds like it is exactly what you want.  Note the [license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readline) if this commercial code though.

Comment: It is an open source solution that could be used in commercial applications, so the license must be flexible.  I will look into it though.

Comment: While readline does appear to be a viable solution (code-wise), it is, unfortunately, under the GPL (and not the LGPL) which may not be an acceptable license.  My application is broken into two components though.  A library where all of the real code goes, and the executable which is nothing more than a shell to call the library.  If I used readline in the shell (not in the library), would only the shell need to be GPL'ed?  How would one legally separate the two?

Comment: I am not a lawyer so I won't venture an opinion on that.  There is a package similar to readline that has a more permissive license but I don't recall the name.  You might want to ask around about that.

Comment: The wikipedia page for readline lists a few, but they either pull in ncurses as a dependency, or they are not as portable as I would like.  Because I could find no viable solution that fits my needs, I ended up working around the need to read/parse more codes than I already do. I would really like to use readline as it seems like a cleaner, better way, and I am accepting this as a solution (for others), but its license is too restrictive.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

If your not doing a GUI or Windowing system, take a look at the `ncurses` library package.

Comment: ncurses requires you to clear the screen so it is not a viable solution.  I think you can use filter() to use certain ncurses functions without initializing the screen, but its a pretty large dependency for such a tiny requirement (and all of the other apps I checked out that achieved this same task, do it without pulling in additional dependancies)